# recursive friend classes

Tags: c++, friend, friend-class

Is there any way around this:

```
class B;

class C { 
 public:
  C() { }
 private:
  int i;
  friend B::B();
};

class B { 
 public:
  B() { }
 private:
  int i;
  friend C::C();
};
```

Gives error:

```
prog.cpp:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B’
prog.cpp:1: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B’
```

Comment: I think the closest you can get is `friend class B`

Comment: What exactly did you want to do that you needed the constructor of B and C to be visible to each other?

Comment: @Mike, that is actually a synthetic example. The real situation is that, for reason to complicated to go into, I can't allow a dependency on C to force a dependency on the the definition of B.

Answer (score 5):

You just can't do this. Remove the circular dependency.

Comment: You can grant friendship to the whole class recursively, just not to individual members.

Answer (score 3):

According to [IBM's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc13cplr042.htm) (which I realize is not normative):

> A class Y must be defined before any member of Y can be declared a friend of another class.

So I think the answer is "no".

Of course, you can use

```
friend class B;
```

...instead of `friend B::B()`, but that grants friendship to all of B's members.  And you probably already knew that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're very selective about friendship (access to specific member functions given to specific classes), the [Attorney-Client Idiom](http://drdobbs.com/184402053) may be what you need. I'm not sure how well this will work with constructors, though.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is a really silly idea, but couldn't you—theoretically—accomplish this through inheritance, by making the parent class' constructors friends? The code compiles, at least, questionable though it may be.

```
class A {
 public:
  A() { }
 private:
  int i;
};

class D {
 public:
  D() { }
 private:
  int i;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  B() { }
 private:
  friend D::D();
};

class C : public D {
 public:
  C() { }
 private:
  friend A::A();
};
```

Comment: I think friendship can't be inherited ... C is not a friend of B and B it not a friend of C here ...

Comment: Friendship definitely is not inherited.

Comment: True. But if you just wanted to give the constructors access to private variables, this would make the private data in B and C accessible to the constructors of B and C's parent classes—which can be respectively called by B and C's constructors—even though B and C cannot access each other's private data directly.