# friend class with forward class declaration does not compile

Tags: c++, friend, friend-class

This a basic program to understand how to use `friend class` in C++.

Class `xxx` has a class `yyy` object using `friend`. Since class `yyy`
is defined after class `xxx` I have declared class `yyy` using forward
declaration.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class yyy; //Forward Declaration of class yyy

class xxx{
private:
  int a;

public:
  xxx(){a=20;yyy y2;y2.show();}       //Error//
  void show(){cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;}
  friend class yyy; //Making class yyy as freind of class xxx
};
class yyy{
private:
  int b;

public:
  yyy(){b=10;}
  void show(){cout<<"b="<<b<<endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  xxx x1; //creating xxx object and calling constructor
  x1.show();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program I get this error:

> error: aggregate ‘yyy y2’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

I referred to this link
[recursive friend classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158760/recursive-friend-classes)
and someone had answered like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158833/2168706

I am following this approach but I am still unable to solve the
issue. Please provide a solution if any exists and please let me know
if I am wrong at any point in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your're instantiating an object `y2` of incomplete type `yyy` here:

```
{ a = 20; yyy y2; y2.show(); }
```

Move the implementation of constructor below the definition of `yyy` class:

```
class yyy;

class xxx {
  private:
    int a;

  public: 
    xxx();

    void show() { cout << "a=" << a << endl; }

    friend class yyy;
};

class yyy {
  private:
    int b;

  public:
    yyy() { b = 10; }

    void show() { cout << "b=" << b << endl; }
};

xxx::xxx() { a = 20; yyy y2; y2.show(); } // No error
```

As a result, at this point `yyy` is already defined, and you can instantiate `y2`.

To give you a logical explanation, why your variant didn't work: when you instantiate an object with **automatic storage duration** (on stack) like `yyy y2;`, compiler has to know at **compile-time** how much memory it should reserve for `y2`. Since the `yyy` type is incomplete (was only forward declared at the point of instantiation), the compiler is lost and reports an error.

**NOTE:** The best practice, is of course to separate definition of the class and its implementation by moving definition to header file (`.hpp`) and implementation to source file (`.cpp`). Don't forget to include headers properly. I don't feel like giving you an example here because it's very basic stuff and should be covered by any C++ book or a tutorial.

Comment: It does not work because y.Show() was not declared yet before you called it. Haroogan's solution will fix that.

Comment: Of course, if that implementation remains in the header, you may get linker errors; you should put it in a .cpp file or mark it inline.

Comment: Thanks Harogan for the reply.