# forward declaration of ‘struct bb’, classes

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I **almost** solved issues with my code with the help of stackoverflow users but now have different problem. My code now looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class root
{
public:
    virtual ~root() {}

    virtual root* addA(const root& a) const=0;
    virtual root* addB(const root& b) const=0;
};

class bb;

class aa: public root
{
public:
    aa() { }
    aa(const aa& a) { }

    root* addA(const root& a) const
    {
        return new aa();
    }

    root* addB(const root& b) const
    {
        return new bb();
    }
};

class bb: public root
{
public:
    bb() { }
    bb(const bb& b) { }

    root* addA(const root& a) const
    {
        return new aa();
    }

    root* addB(const root& b) const
    {
        return new bb();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

But when I compile it, it gives errors:

```
/home/brain/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp||In member function ‘virtual root* aa::addB(const root&) const’:|
/home/brain/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|30|error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct bb’|
/home/brain/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.cpp|15|error: forward declaration of ‘struct bb’|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: @Mat I think the dependency problem can be fixed by putting the definitions of the relevant methods in implementation files. The design is still fishy though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case, you can move the definitions of the member function to after class `bb` has been defined. OR preferably put them in a **separate `.cpp`** file and `include` the header.

```
class aa: public root
{
public:
    // ....
    root* addB(const root& b) const;
    // Declaration only
};


class bb: public root
{
public:
    // ....
};

// Here.
inline    // <--- If you define it in the header.
root* aa::addB(const root& b) const
{
    return new bb();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since compiler doesn't have any idea about class `bb` so it wont be able to create an object and return it `return bb()`

It will work if you define the `root* addB(const root& b) const` outside the class, because at that time it would be able to know the size of class `bb`.

Comment: Please refet to the below link for the similar question asked..               http://stackoverflow.com/q/16398416/2168706